# How to pass values from server to angular

Tags: angularjs

Here i'm using Angular with mvc During edit mode how to pass values

```
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Edit" ng-click="EditUser(ee)"  />
```

When i click on edit button model is popup but why values not binding in textbox

```
 <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="User.Name" />
 <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="User.Eamil" />
```

if i change User.Name  to Name then its wirking Fine

```
 $scope.EditUser = function (ee) {
                  var serdata = Generalsrvs.EditService(ee.User.UserId);
                    serdata.then(function () {

                        $scope.User.UserId = ee.User.UserId,
                        $scope.User.Name  = ee.Name,
                        $scope.User.Eamil = ee.Eamil

                       $('#modalpop').modal('show');

                    })
```

Comment: Does your modal has the same controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you just want to pass values.,

According to the [AngularJS:API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) , you can simply do this:

```
<div ng-init="myModule=value-here">
   //something
</div>
```